# which commands may i use to load i/o kit driver in terminal?

Tags: macos, sdk, iokit, kernel-extension

i am new kernel programming.i have been trying to load this driver program for 3 days.

i used so many commands for load this kext file.but every time the problem is

terminal.please any one help me .

ensiss-Mac-mini:~ ensis$ sudo su

sh-3.2#  chown -R root:wheel /System/Library/Extensions/Driver.kext

sh-3.2# kextutil -n -t /System/Library/Extensions/Driver.kext No kernel file specified;

using running kernel for linking.

/System/Library/Extensions/Driver.kext is invalid; can't resolve dependencies.

/System/Library/Extensions/Driver.kext is invalid; can't resolve dependencies.

/System/Library/Extensions/Driver.kext is invalid; can't resolve dependencies.

Diagnostics for /System/Library/Extensions/Driver.kext:

Validation Failures:

```
Info dictionary missing required property/value: 

    IOKitPersonalities.Driver.IOClass
```

Warnings:

```
Personality has no CFBundleIdentifier; the kext's identifier will be inserted when
```

sending to the IOCatalogue:

```
    Driver
```

how to resolve the above program

**Update:** Info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">;
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Driver</key>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleIdentifier </key>
       <string>com.Driver.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
      <key>IOClass </key>
       <string>com_osxkernel_driver_Driver</string>
      <key>IOMatchCategory </key>
       <string>com_osxkernel_driver_Driver</string>
      <key>IOProviderClass</key>
       <string>IOResources</string>
      <key>IOResourceMatch </key>
       <string>IOKit</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">;
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.kpi.iokit </key>
     <string>11.3.0</string>
    <key>com.apple.kpi.libkern </key>
     <string>11.3.0</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Looks like a direct follow-up of your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769241/which-commands-may-i-use-to-load-i-o-kit-driver-in-terminal. Please next time mention this so people would know that you've tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is here:

"Info dictionary missing required property/value: IOKitPersonalities.Driver.IOClass"

This means your Info.plist is incorrect as your driver's personality description is missing a class specification.

Have you worked through Apple's [Creating a Device Driver with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptIOKit/iokit_tutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002366-CIHECHHE) tutorial? The section [Edit the Information Property List](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptIOKit/iokit_tutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002366-CIHECHHE) covers the minimum you need to know about this. The documentation on [Driver and Device Matching](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Matching/Matching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000015-TP9) goes into more detail.

**Update:**

Your info.plist has completely the wrong format. Take a look at [this screenshot](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/art/Driver_PlistComplete.jpg) from the tutorial I linked above for the required hierarchy. The XCode project template for the I/O Kit Driver generates a sensible starting point for an info.plist - *don't* delete what it gives you, just extend it.

I strongly suggest you thoroughly read the documentation from Apple, some of their sample code, and get the [recently released book by Halvorsen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430235365) along with its [sample code (source code/downloads tab)](http://www.apress.com/9781430235361-4892). (disclosure: I was one of the reviewers of the book; I do not receive royalties or any other incentive for recommending it - it's the only up-to-date book on the subject)

Kernel programming is anything but easy, so it's important you understand what's going on.

Comment: Thank you. may i chat with you

Comment: I suggest you post your info.plist

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>Driver</key>
 <dict>
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier  </key>
  <string>com.Driver.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>
  <key>IOClass    </key>
  <string>com_osxkernel_driver_Driver</string>
  <key>IOMatchCategory  </key>
  <string>com_osxkernel_driver_Driver</string>
  <key>IOProviderClass</key>
  <string>IOResources</string>
  <key>IOResourceMatch </key>
  <string>IOKit</string>
 </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>com.apple.kpi.iokit  </key>
 <string>11.3.0</string>
 <key>com.apple.kpi.libkern </key>
 <string>11.3.0</string>
</dict>
</plist>

Comment: When providing listings, *please* update the question itself. I've done it for you this time, but in future please make some effort.

Comment: are you willing to come on chat? Previously i didin't take any coaching for kernel.And also i got that book.would you please tell me which is the better path to learn kernel? presently i am using 10.7.3 mac os x and 4.2 xcode.I wanna to speak with you and learn something from you.

Comment: @MedetiNaveenKumar Sorry, I hope you'll understand I can't afford to give free private coaching to everyone. As for the best way to learn kernel programming: 1. it would probably help to know your level of C/C++ proficiency - what's the biggest thing you've built in C or C++? 2. What are you hoping to achieve by learning how to do kernel programming? What do you want to build?

Comment: i understand your situation.thank you reply my comment.It is the great help you did.In the time of learning i ask some doubts.at least please help me those things.would you please refer any books or pdf for kernel programming because i am the single person to learn kernel without anyone help.                                                                                              Thanking you,                                                            with regards,                                                      naveen.

Comment: The good news is: I taught myself from books and the web, too. You haven't answered my 2 questions though: what are you ultimately trying to achieve, and what is your C/C++ experience? The book and Apple docs I've mentioned are pretty thorough and should get you quite far if your knowledge of C and C++ is sufficient.

Comment: Hi friend,sorry last few days my account was suspended so i didn't reply your comment.i am good in c and c++.i have a good knowledge in data structures.I studied the apple documents but lack of experience in this programming i face so much of difficulty to understand each point.my main goal to study this programming is to develop a device drivers.